# Can I describe a specific piano training/learning situation and ask if it's a bad practice?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The title pretty much summarises my intent.

Basically, I am learning piano without a private teacher but rather following some lessons, because of which I can only rely on following the instructions without having any feedbacks.

I was wondering if this is on topic here? It seems to fit the "practice & performance technique" point from the tour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like a good fit to me!

There is an opinion-based aspect to this question, but frankly the majority of pedagogical questions do have some opinion in them. And these questions tend to fall cleanly into the realm of acceptable subjective questions as given in the SE [Help Center](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

**Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be *constructive*.** What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:

- inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
- tend to have long, not short, answers
- have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
- invite sharing experiences over opinions
- insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
- are more than just mindless social fun